# Asp.net MVC post data to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post data to controller using Jquery, AddToCArt function is not hitting by jquery.

here is my view:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @{
                <!--List For Kgs to populate dropDown-->
                List<SelectListItem> KgItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
                KgItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1 kg", Value = "1" });

                <!--List of Dozens to populate dropDown-->
                List<SelectListItem> DozenItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
                DozenItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1 Dozen", Value = "1" });

                if (item.WeightType == "Kg")
                {
                    @Html.DropDownList("Weight", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)KgItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
                }
                else if (item.WeightType == "Dozen")
                {
                    @Html.DropDownList("Weight", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)DozenItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
                } 
            }
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit" value="Add to Cart" />
        </div>
```

here is my Jquery: -

```
<script>
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        var w8 = $("#Weight option:selected").text();
        alert("Selected Weight " + w8);
        $.post("/Test/AddToCart",
        {
            value: w8
        });
    });
```

here is my controller: -

```
public void AddToCart(int value)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //here is some code
    }
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not related to the question, just a note. Shortenings like "for -> 4", "weight -> w8" can quickly render your code unreadable, best avoid them.

Comment: Does your action get hit if you enter in the browser address manually:  `http://localhost/Test/AddToCart?value=123`? (change localhost to your server/add port)

Comment: are you getting the alert at alert("Selected Weight " + w8) ?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that could go wrong here.

First, you are using `data: Id`, but variable `Id` does not seem to be defined in this context. Did you actually mean `data: w8`?

Second, you are posting data in form `"data": 123`, but expecting, according to your action declaration, data in form `"value": 123`. These need to be in sync.

So it looks like your posting code should look like that

```
$.post("/Test/AddToCart",
    {
        value: w8
    });
```

Third thing is that you are not preventing default behavior of your button. You can do so with `return false` or calling `preventDefault`, like so:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
    ...
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @BilalMustafa, added one more possible cause

Answer (score 0):

You might need the `HttpPost` attribute on your action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(int value)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //here is some code
    }
```

After all, what you should be doing first, is to check your browser developer console, to see what the actual problem is.

Comment: `[HttpPost]` *limits* the action to be POST only (ie it will fail if you call it with a GET).  It's not needed to indicate that this is a post method *unless* there is another action overload in the controller (with the same name used for GET).  Which doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: We don't actually know if there is or isn't any other method with the same name in the controller. That's why I said 'You might'.

Comment: i don't know why function is not hitting by JQuery call.

Comment: Hitting `F12` on your keyboard would bring you the developer console, which you can see the errors happening (check for the console tab there). You should be investigating those errors instead of just freaking out :)

Answer (score 0):

It could possible be that the controller is expecting an integer value passed. A quick check would be to set this value to a string to see if it hits. Otherwise you could try the suggestion below.

Try parse the weight value

`var weightValue = parseInt(w8);`

**Updated Code below:**

```
<script>
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var w8 = $("#Weight option:selected").text();
    var weightValue = parseInt(w8);
    alert("Selected Weight " + weightValue);
    $.post("/Test/AddToCart",
    {
        value: weightValue 
    });
});
```

**Questions:**

- Have you set a breakpoint on the controller action and is it getting hit?
- Any console errors linked to the client side?

Comment: Nice one! Make sure to use the debugging tools on the browser when working with JavaScript/Jquery it will save you a lot of time. Useful link https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Your `using (Html.BeginForm())` is inside the for loop. This means you will create as many form tags as there are elements in the loop. So place your `using (Html.BeginForm())` before you begin the loop.

Also this will generate multiple submit buttons with exactly the same id, which is absolutely wrong as html element id must be unique

Answer (score 0):

Please Change following some bit changes and try.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit" value="Add to Cart" />

**TO**

<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit" value="Add to Cart" />
```

And

```
 $.post("/Test/AddToCart",
        {
            value: w8
        });

**TO**

 $.post('@Url.Action("Test", "AddToCart")',
        {
            value: +w8
        });
```

And

```
    public void AddToCart(int value)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //here is some code
        }
    }

**TO**

  [HttpPost]
  public void AddToCart(int value)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //here is some code
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

```
<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @{
                <!--List For Kgs to populate dropDown-->
                List<SelectListItem> KgItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
                KgItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1 kg", Value = "1" });

                <!--List of Dozens to populate dropDown-->
                List<SelectListItem> DozenItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
                DozenItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1 Dozen", Value = "1" });

                if (item.WeightType == "Kg")
                {
                    @Html.DropDownList("Weight"+@item.id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)KgItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
                }
                else if (item.WeightType == "Dozen")
                {
                    @Html.DropDownList("Weight"+@item.id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)DozenItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
                } 
            }
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">
                <input type="buton" class="btn btn-success" onclick="funcationname(@item.id)" id="btnSubmit" value="Add to Cart" />
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>

funcationname(id)
{
var w8 = $("#Weight"+ id + " option:selected").text();
        $.post("/Test/AddToCart",
        {
            value: +w8
        });
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy it's hitting but now facing a new problem

Comment: what the problem?

Comment: i have many products in page, when i select weight and press add to cart button it only works on first product and not on all others... lol

Comment: Please call  foreach under the using (Html.BeginForm())

Comment: "ID" available  in this model?

Comment: `@Url.Action("Test", "AddToCart")` should be `@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")` with controller optional.

Comment: Best practice is to wire up events in javascript (/jquery) and not to use `onclick=`.

Comment: you are right but this is a dynamic so id not same at this case onclick is better than javascript event.

Answer (score 0):

**here is working view**

```
<div class="row">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{   
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
       @{
            <!--List For Kgs to populate dropDown-->
            List<SelectListItem> KgItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            KgItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1 kg", Value = "1" });

            <!--List of Dozens to populate dropDown-->
            List<SelectListItem> DozenItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            DozenItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1 Dozen", Value = "1" });

            if (item.WeightType == "Kg")
            {
                @Html.DropDownList("Weight", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)KgItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
            }
            else if (item.WeightType == "Dozen")
            {
                @Html.DropDownList("Weight", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)DozenItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
            }
         }
     }
}
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit" value="Add to Cart" />
</div>
```

here is working Jquery: -

```
<script>
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var w8 = $("#Weight option:selected").val();
    alert("Selected Weight " + w8);
    $.post("/Home/AddToCart",
        {
            value: w8
        });
});
```

here is working controller: -

```
public void AddToCart(int value)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //here is some code
    }
}
```

Comment: @Bilal Mustafa i have check and run the example ant it's work fine

Comment: welcome @BilalMustafa please mark answer as useful if you got solution